# Particles facing wrong direction

Tags: particles

I added the particles to a plan and they stood up as expected. I then applied a lattice to the plane and now the grass is sideways. Is there anyway to rotate the grass upwards again?

Answer (score 1):

never mind. I changed the velocities and it fixed it